# How to configure Microsoft edge based on chromium to run robotframework with python automation script

Tags: robotframework

Looking out for steps to configure microsoft edge based on chromium to launch robotframework script using python.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just need to search for a bit and you'd find that you [need a webdriver](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary#browser-drivers), which will take you to this [Microsoft site with webdrivers for Edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/).

When you have the driver and everything is set up, you can open Edge browser using [`Open Browser`](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser) keyword.

Comment: Steps Followed:downloaded the webdriver and aadded in path,installed edge browser but getting error ...no keyword with name " open browser" found

Comment: Hard to say without the code. Learn how to debug such small problems, read the documentation, look for differences between your code and documentation examples. You could find the problem on your own.

Answer (score 0):

From the previous comments i figured that you have installed the edge driver and you are not able to find open browser command. Here is the Solution
Install Selenium library using command

pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary

pip install -U selenium

Import them

Then you will easily find the command Open Browser!
Let me know if it Helps!